# CSS "background-image" not showing in IE8 and below

Tags: html, css

No matter what I do I cannot get the `background-image` property to work correctly in IE8.
I've even stripped everything down to the bare minimum and just have a functioning HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Fritz PT!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="myClass">

    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

with the CSS for the class as follows:

```
.myClass {
    background-image: url(/images/header_image_fallback.gif);
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

but still nothing is showing up in IE8 and lower.

I have tried multiple image formats (.gif, .jpg, .png), putting quotes around the folder path ('/images/header_image_fallback.gif') and then HTML. Does IE8 not support the background-image property? If it makes a difference I'm currently testing this out in VirtualBox.

Comment: Not sure this is answerable with the current code. We'd have to see it *not* working.

Comment: This is literally all the code that is used. I don't know I can't figure it out. Sounds like this is something highly abnormal then from your response. Maybe I'll just have to try and use another method.

Comment: Are you saying it works in other broswers but not IE8?

Comment: Ya, I found out the answer though which I'm going to post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if anyone else is having the same problem as me I found the issue. Apparently, even though the syntax works in all modern browsers, you need to make sure you have the ../ for the folder path for IE. So in my original code (which works in modern browsers) I had the folder path as seen above /images/header_image_fallback.gif however, for IE I would need to do this ../images/header_image_fallback.gif. My images folder is up a directory from my css file and I suppose that matters for IE as opposed to modern browsers